# Joining rows in CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV (~1.5m rows) in the following format:

```
id, tag1, tag2, name1, value1
```

There are several rows with the same id. If a row has the same id, it will have the same tag1 and tag2. So, what I want to do is to append in the end of the row the `name1, value1` which will be different.

Example:

```
Original:
    id,tag1,tag2,name1,value1
    12,orange,car,john,32
    13,green,bike,george,23
    12,orange,car,elen,21
Final:
    id,tag1,tag2,name1,value1
    12,orange,car,john,32,elen,21
    13,green,bike,george,23
```

The only way I can do it is with a brute force script in Python. Create a dictionary with the key of the id and then a list with all the other parameters. Each time I find an id which is already in the dictionary, I just append the last two fields in the dictionary value as a list.

However, it is not the most efficient way to do it in such a big file. Is there any other way to do it, maybe with a library?

Comment: Actually it is the most efficient way to do this assuming you have enough memory for all the data.

Comment: According to your example your data isn't sorted, then using your approach is the only viable solution. If the data was sorted, then you would only have to keep the last read line in memory.

Comment: @Kay Can you give an answer for a sorted CSV, so I can accept it? I can easily sort the CSV before start working on it.

Comment: @Tasos Sorting CSV is by far less efficient then using dicts. You do realize that your solution is `O(n)` while solution with sorting is `O(n*log(n))`? If you have enough memory then you are good as you are. And if you don't have enough memory then you still have to implement sorting outside of memory which is not trivial.

Comment: @freakish I export the CSV from a database and I can add the option of sorting on there. So, I don't calculate the time of it in the script. Sorry if I wasn't clear before.

Comment: @Tasos If you export the CSV from a database then why don't you do the proper grouping in your query? Assuming you use a db that supports it.

Comment: @freakish I don't have access by myself and sorting is something simple to ask from a grouping. However, in the meantime, I put my script running with the way in the question and after several minutes have finished.

Comment: @Tasos Well, you've asked about an efficient way, not a simple way. :D To be honest I doubt it will be faster with sorting. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: In my experience at least MySQL is terrible at sorting huge datasets. I won't rule out that using a dict is actually the best solution.

Comment: I *really* feel like this a major X-Y Problem. Your comments say this data comes from a database, but you don't tell us what database you're exporting from or *why* you have a limitation to use only Python. I consider that information crucial. With those pieces of information, we're likely to come up with something that never occurred to you. E.g., if your database is PostgreSQL, some ideas about how you could transform it prior to exporting come to mind immediately (possibly with a little post-processing after exporting). You could well be limiting your options here by hiding info from us.

Comment: You could additionally query the database directly from Python and process the data on the way out instead exporting to CSV first.

Answer (score 0):

Kay's suggestion using sorted input data could look something like this:

```
with open('in.txt') as infile, open('out.txt', mode='w') as outfile:
    # Prime the first line
    line = infile.readline()
    # When collating lines, running_line will look like:
    # ['id,tag1,tag2', 'name1', 'value1', 'name2', 'value2', ...]
    # Prime it with just the 'id,tag1,tag2' of the first line
    running_line = [line[:-1].rsplit(',', 2)[0]]
    while line:
        curr_it12, name, value = line[:-1].rsplit(',', 2)
        if running_line[0] == curr_it12:
            # Current line's id/tag1/tag2 matches previous line's.
            running_line.extend([name, value])
        else:
            # Current line's id/tag1/tag2 doesn't match. Output the previous...
            outfile.write(','.join(running_line) + '\n')
            # ...and start a new running_line
            running_line = [curr_it12, name, value]
        # Grab the next line
        line = infile.readline()
    # Flush the last line
    outfile.write(','.join(running_line) + '\n')
```